# WebKit as a form control with C++

Tags: c++, webkit

Hi there I am looking for a way to include the WebKit renderer engine in my C++ Win32 Form, maybe as a control? I have messed around with WebKit .NET but I don't want my app to be dependant on the .NET framework.

I know there is chromiumembedded and Brent Fulgham's OpenCFLite none of which look that simple to use. I am not the strongest C++ programmer and haven't even set up a project in years. A step by step tutorial would be nice or an already built test app which I can just modify?

Comment: you could also use QT that has native support for webkit

Comment: I have seen it around, I am not 100% sure how to build a project with all those source files etc I have made a dice game in C++ from scratch that's about as far as my C++ skill gets :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you the chance to use QT in your project? is easy to use and quick!

http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qtwebkit.html

Comment: Looks like the thing I need the app I want to make is standalone and small will this build small apps? :)

Comment: QT are developed also for smarthphone, so with few resources, I think that there are a perfect match for your app :)